# configuration approach

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I have a solution containing 13 projects. The solution is configured to start multiple projects. A lot of these project need to go to shared databases and web services.

My `app.config` and `web.config` files now contain a lot of duplication. Eg when I want to change a database I need to change all the configuration files in the projects (`app.config`s) that access that database.

I wonder what the best approach is to tackle this? Is there a way to define solution wide configuration settings in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a class library project, referenced by your other projects, just for configuration purposes (if none of your other libraries already within the solution are already shared by all projects), which has the shared/central app.config file associated to it.

The library would need to expose the configuration settings so that they can be consumed elsewhere within the solution.

The team I work with has a library of common helper classes, one of which is a configuration helper as described above.  This works well for us because this library is included with all (well - unless inappropriate to do so) our projects so seems the "natural" place to store those shared settings.

Comment: With this approach, you will still have to duplicate the content of this application settings into each project's configuration

Comment: @SteveB Not exactly. App.config and web.config allow you to redirect some of the tags to an external XML file (via configSource). Therefore, you can extract the common settings to a single XML file, and then link to app.config and web.config. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228167(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @SteveB any custom settings that would otherwise be added to eg "ConsoleApplicationX.config" are instead added to "CentralLibrary.config". eg `<applicationSettings>
<CentralLibrary.Properties.Settings>
<setting name="sharedSetting" serializeAs="String">
<value>0</value>
</setting>
</CentralLibrary.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>`.  For things such as shared connection strings, we'd add these as custom strings for example.  These settings would never be duplicated, as they wouldn't be stored in the "target" ConsoleApplicationX's own config setting. This works.  Did I miss the point?

Comment: @SteveB admittedly this is a hangover from a library that started back at v1.1, that I think was "bent" to fit 2.0.  But Lex's comment above does suggest there's better ways to do this.  But as I said, this works.